# Como faço pra concatenar informações no sql?

Tags: sql, pl-sql

Olá, tenho a tabela abaixo:

```
PEDIDO     COLEÇÃO
1296530    A 1/2022-INVERNO
1296530    B 1/2022-INVERNO
```

Quero que fique assim:

```
PEDIDO     COLEÇÃO
1296530    A 1/2022-INVERNO, B 1/2022-INVERNO
```

Já tentei a função `concat(co.descricao,',')` que vi em outro lugar mas ele retorno do mesmo mesmo jeito que a primeira somente com a vírgula acrescentada. Como faço? Eu uso o `PL/SQL`.

Comment: No MySQL tem algo chamado GROUP_CONCAT que faz isso o que você quer.  Para outros bancos de dados SQL existem outras formas de fazer Eu recomendo você dar uma olhada neste link onde existem exemplos de como resolver isso em outros bancos de dados  https://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/group_concat

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Comment: Eu pesquisei nos links que vc mandou mas não consegui resolver meu problema, mas muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: O que deu de errado ? Isto funciona (listagg) já usei muito.

Answer (score -2):

Experimente utilizar :

```
LISTAGG(co.descricao, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1)
```